# Flutter pub get Error - easy_localization

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image]

I upgraded to Flutter. The problem continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this lines below your dependencies to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependency_overrides:
  path: ^1.8.0-nullsafety.1
```

Comment: thanks bro, "flutter pub upgrade" with solved.